# Can't flash the module — 'Please insert disk'

Tags: mbed

I recently got a new Mbed board - this one is [MTS Dragonfly](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/MTS-Dragonfly/). I can't get flash-disk to show up correctly, and I am wondering if I have got a DOA module, or I am doing something wrong. Does this happens to other Mbed boards?

I have installed drivers from manufacturer website and do have a working serial connection, which defaults to the cellular module. However the flash disk does not show up correctly. Unlike other Mbed boards, I am greeted with a message "please insert disk" and I see no file system.

[image: Please insert disk - what the hell?]

**Interesting part** is that the mbed microcontroller - that is the one doing the programming - is on a separate development / breakout board. The target is a separate module that is meant to be used in production.

If I do not insert the target into the development board, and connect development board to the PC, I get the same error. I have looked at diskpart, and when no target is present, it shows up as a 16 KB disk with no partitions or volumes.When the module is inserted, diskpart reports ~512 KB of space, also with no partitions. Thus I guess that I am plugging in the module correctly.

[image: Diskpart Report]

I have seen user discussions for a 'bricked' mbed board (damaged file-system), and this situation looks similar to me. 
I tried diskpart to create a partition, or clean the disk, and it throws an IO error.

[This question on mbed site](https://developer.mbed.org/questions/73554/Cant-flash-the-module-Please-insert-disk/)

Comment: As stated in your answer, it's a problem with STLink, so only affecting ST boards.

Comment: Didn't realize this at first, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested all of my Mbed boards and discovered that this is a regression in Windows 10 anniversary update. 
 MTS-Dragonfly and another board, Delta DFCM-NNN40, do not show up with a valid partition on any of my Windows 10 machines. I have a couple of FRDM boards and those work fine.

I tested Ubuntu, and it has no issue displaying the disk drives or programming the boards. I have not tested other versions of Windows. A workable solution is is to use Ubuntu in VirtualBox, and pass it control of the USB device.